# Завека / за века

Tags: орфография

Как правильно писать?

> За век, за века, за веки.

> Завек, завека, завеки.

Comment: А в каком тексте вы хотите использовать "за веки". В чем проблема для "за век, за века"? Этот вопрос лучше задать так: Как правильно записать и объяснить слова: (на)век, (на)веки, (на)века и (за)век, (за)веки, (за)века.

Comment: Можете это объяснить-таки?

Comment: Давайте завтра, ОК?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно:

***За век, за века, за веки.***

**Пояснение**

1. Во всех случаях **падежное управление** предлога ***ЗА*** (В.п.): за что?

Но значение слов разное: ***За век*** и ***за века*** — это за какой период времени, падежная форма используется часто. А вот ***за веки*** вызывает сомнение.

Из Нацкорпуса: *Лицо его — лицо трагика, расширяется в ласково-покровительственную улыбку, глаза, будто слегка успокоившись, прячутся ***за веки.****

Тогда понятно: **ВЕКО**, -а; ср. Подвижная складка кожи, прикрывающая глазное яблоко. Верхнее, нижнее в. Опухшие, покрасневшие веки (признак утомления, недосыпания и т.п.). Смежить веки (закрыть глаза).

2. Но почему нет наречий со слитным написанием: ***завек, завеки завека?***

Сравним со словами: ***навек*** и ***на век***, ***навеки, на века.*** Здесь в некоторых случаях возможно управление падежом: ***на век, на века.***

Обратим внимание на наречия ***навек*** и ***навеки.***

Большой толковый словарь:
***НАВЕК; НАВЕКИ***, нареч. **Навсегда**, на всю жизнь. Н. полюбить. Н. запомнить что-л. Прощай н.

Но как различить ***навек*** и ***на век***?. Это видно из приведенных примеров:

*Наталья Курчанова, факультет культуры, IV курс: «Скажите о ваших главных разочарованиях конца XX века и главных надеждах ***на век следующий.****

*Очень хочется экстраполировать сей процесс хотя бы ***на век вперед*** — до той поры, когда люди научатся чинить себя так, как сейчас они чинят компьютеры и их операционные системы.*

```
 С любимыми не расставайтесь!
 Всей кровью прорастайте в них,-
 И каждый раз НАВЕК прощайтесь!
 Когда уходите на миг!
```

**[Стихотворение](https://rupoem.ru/kochetkov/kak-bolno-milaya.aspx)** Александра Кочеткова «Баллада о прокуренном вагоне» написано в 1932 г. и имеет реальную историю происхождения.